# Anything special on the ratio of partial over total functions?

Tags: functions, partial-functions

The number of functions that maps an element in $A$ to another one in $A$ is $|A|^{|A|}$ for finite size of $A$, and the number of partial functions that maps an element in $A$ to another one in $A$ is $(1+|A|)^{|A|}$. If we divide the second by the first we get $$\frac{(1+|A|)^{|A|}}{|A|^{|A|}}=\left(\frac{1+|A|}{|A|}\right)^{|A|}=\left(1+\frac 1{|A|}\right)^{|A|}$$

whose limit is $e=2.71...$ as the size of $A$ goes to infinity, so by Cesaro lemma , in average, there $e$ times more partial functions that total functions. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Your calculations aren't reason enough?

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Yes, but I was looking for some kind of insight related with $e$ that makes this true, if there is not and the result is just coincidence, that's good too.

Comment: If you look at maps from A to B instead of just maps from A to A, then you even get exp(|A|/|B|) as the ratio of partial over total functions. I agree with Garmekain that it would be nice to get some kind of insight why this is so (and not merely a coincidence).